# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'

Tags: python, torch

I'm trying to to write a simple python app and launch it using TorchX following [this](https://pytorch.org/torchx/latest/quickstart.html#Quickstart) Quickstart guide. Following commands are executed in my home directory:

1. `pip3 install "torchx[dev]"`
2. Write a simple python program using vim editor `vi my_app.py`
3. 

```
# my_app.py
%%writefile my_app.py
    
import sys
    
print(f"Hello, {sys.argv[1]}!")
```

4. Execute the app via `torchx run` as `torchx run --scheduler local_cwd utils.python --script my_app.py "your name"`.

And then I get a long error:

```
Log files located in: /var/folders/h7/qrsyzj5s7hvbkwmv83by9wgc0000gn/T/torchx_hykfxkz3/torchx/torchx_utils_python-vxm9hhpt3k7wtd/python/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/torchx", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchx/cli/main.py", line 110, in main
    run_main(get_sub_cmds(), argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchx/cli/main.py", line 106, in run_main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchx/cli/cmd_run.py", line 271, in run
    self._run(runner, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchx/cli/cmd_run.py", line 232, in _run
    app_handle = runner.run_component(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchx/runner/api.py", line 147, in run_component
    return self.schedule(dryrun_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchx/runner/api.py", line 225, in schedule
    app_id = sched.schedule(dryrun_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchx/schedulers/local_scheduler.py", line 748, in schedule
    replica = self._popen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchx/schedulers/local_scheduler.py", line 688, in _popen
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'
```

I have Python 3.9.13 installed on macOS Monterey (version 12.4).
What could be a cause of this error?

Comment: I've gotten the same error message, but in very different use case. It only occurred on our CI job in Gitlab, and seemed to be caused by an issue during caching/extraction of the venv folder. See: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14613